# How to avoid displaying Google Adwords when searching with special case (such as inurl, site) ?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, google-ads, ppc

We are using Google, Which is very expensive now. I want to avoid displaying my Ads when someone search using keyword site:somedomain.com or inurl or some other specific cases like that.

What is the way to avoid my Ads when someone searches like that ? 
if i can avoid displaying, then we can save some money.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to exclude potential visitors from AdWords based on whether they searched using a search operator.

However, most people don't know how to search using operators. The average person won't be using any of them. People who use these mostly include SEO's and search system developers and maybe Library Science majors or professional researchers. You probably aren't losing a lot of money by showing ads to these people once in a blue moon.

To prevent having these ads cost you when you or someone from your company is doing a search using operators, use a CPC rather than a CPM plan. (It'll decrease the chances of users draining your budget with wasted impressions in general.) You can also exclude your own IP address; you won't see ads live at all, but to test your ads you should be using AdWords preview tools anyway.

You can also use audience pools (retargeting audiences; locations) and try to bid on those rather than a more general population.

None of this will absolutely prevent your ads showing to someone who uses search operators, but it'll narrow the chances even further.

Comment: thanks, But, Google should have a option to exclude search operators like negative keywords. Otherwise, small business owners are going to lose money.

Comment: Actually, they do! That's one I forgot to mention. When choosing your keywords, you can use negative keywords. And you can exclude your own site query by putting "site:example.com" in as a negative keyword. (inurl and such will be harder to exclude since that can involve many variations). Not sure how well it will work, since I've never had to exclude search operators when running campaigns, but you can try it, experiment, see what happens. See more here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453972?hl=en

Comment: so, we have to pay for it. It will be very expensive when we have lots of high CPC keywords and most of the competitors or followers of your website will click. Very BAD Google. Already, you are making lots of money by fake clicks.